# Broken TYPO3 front-end (encoding)

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

I have a `TYPO3 4.5.37` website which works perfect on my `local windows enviorement`, but after uploading it to a `Linux environment` I get a broken front-end (the back-end is functioning normally) see:
[image: Broken TYPO3 front-end]

What I already tried;

- Converted all database tables to a utf8_general_ci collation
- [BE][forceCharset] = utf-8
- [SYS][setDBinit] = SET NAMES utf8;

When I drop my database (so there is no connection) the problem with the output is still there so I think this has nothing to do with the database.
The website outputs the front-end with TemplaVoila, I updated TemplaVoila from 1.6.x to 1.9.2 but this didn't work.

On the same server are a lot of other working TYPO3 sites hosted so this has probably nothing to do with the server settings.

I'm running out of options now. So I hope somebody can help me out here.

Comment: As thats totally corrupted I'd wager something to do with gzip compression, try disabling it in the server. Providing the url may help.

Comment: I forgot to tell that on the same server a lot (like 600) other TYPO3 websites are hosted. This is our projects server. I can't provide the url.

Comment: Save that response to a file, open in hex editor, if the first 2 bytes are 1f,8b something is up with gzip/your content headers

Comment: I tried it, the first characters are FF, FE, 1F, 00, FD, FF, 08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The compressionLevel was set to '1' in the install tool, when turned off the problem with the encoding on the front-end disappeared.

> [FE][compressionLevel]
>
> Determines output compression of BE output. Makes output smaller but
>   slows down the page generation depending on the compression level.
>   Requires a) zlib in your PHP installation and b) special rewrite rules
>   for .css.gzip and .js.gzip (please see _.htacces for an example).
>   Range 1-9, where 1 is least compression and 9 is greatest compression.
>   'true' as value will set the compression based on the PHP default
>   settings (usually 5). Suggested and most optimal value is 5.